# Bash - for loop does not print first object

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to understand to understand why my for loop prints all results but the first one:

```
*#!/bin/bash
#python deploy/bulk.py 
countOuter=0
countInner=0
END=23
for bool in $(seq ${1} $END)#$1 $2  $3  $4  $5  $6  $7  $8  $9 ${10} ${11} ${12} ${13} ${14} ${15} ${16} ${17} ${18} ${19} ${20} ${21} ${22} ${23} 
do
countOuter=$((countOuter+1))*
```

My output starts with:
**------------------------------------------------------- EQUALITY<<< 2 : 2>>> EQUALITY-------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------- JOB 1000000bet.com BUILT ----------------------------------------------------------------------**

If I do not use this *$(seq ${1} $END)* but simply *$1  $2  $3  $4  $5  $6  $7  $8  $9.*..., it works.

Comment: please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update the question accordingly; in particular ... `seq ${1} $END` is not the same as `$1 $2 $3 ... $23`; please update the question with contents of `$1` through `$23`, complete set of code, and complete set of output (also apply formatting to the output for readability purposes)

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here (or what you expect to happen), but I think you may be confused about what `$( )` does.

Comment: I am not able to put the whole code, because there are too much sensitive info. I will try to explain. There is a Jenkinsfile passing true/false to my script.sh file. I am using those values to determine whether or not a bulk jobs to be triggered.

Comment: After some playing around last minutes, I realised that this is not working like at all. Even if END=5, it continue to walk through all the 23 objects. There is no problem to use those values the stupid way, but it is kind a strange that it is so hard to implement range in for loop :)

Comment: if you want a simple range then `seq $END` is enough. you could use the format option to append the `$` like this `seq -f "$%g" $END` but it won't work

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- script is provided with 23 input parameters
- OP wishes to process the first `$END` parameters
- full parameter list may be needed later so we don't want to use `shift`

One idea using a loop counter:

```
END=5
pass=0

for bool in "$@"
do
    ((pass++))
    [[ "${pass}" -gt "${END}" ]] && break
    ... process "${bool}" ...
done
```

Another idea using an array:

```
END=5
arr=( "$@" )

for ((i=0;i<END;i++))
do
    ... process "${arr[i]}" ...
done
```

One more idea using indirect variable references:

```
END=5

for ((i=1;i<=END;i++))
do
    ... process "${!i}" ...
done
```